# How to add buy now button URL

Tags: magento-1.8, cart

I am using Magento 1.8. and custom theme.
I have added the button called BUY NOW for each product, and url of that button is
`echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl($_product);`
It redirects to checkout but Its unable to add that product to cart.

How it is possible to add product to cart and redirect to checkout page by on click of BUY NOW button.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer

Comment: Please Go at This url [enter link description here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128673/magento-buy-now-button-for-configurable-products) and read Answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

To add product in the cart and from there you can proceed to checkout.

Try

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
```

This will generate add to cart link

Comment: Its adding the product to url but not redirecting to checkout,

Comment: Can you provide me the generated URL by the above code, by viewing it, I could help you.

Comment: http://enterprise.lmm.dev/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2VudGVycHJpc2UubG1tLmRldi9pbmRleC5waHAva2Z2bmtkdm4uaHRtbA,,/product/26/form_key/8cG1DzIlR4fwy6iX

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've essentially renamed the "Add to cart" button to "Buy now" and would like to by-pass the cart and go directly to the checkout page.

To achieve this do the following:

1. Copy **CartController.php** from **/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/** to **/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers**
2. At line 95 of **CartController.php** replace

   $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

With

```
 $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');
```

To disable this functionality, delete the file from the local sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Magento generates an add to cart url for add to cart buttons.

It's in the form of

`http://{YOUR SITE NAME}/checkout/cart/add/uenc/{Base64 Encoded Redirect Url},/product/{PRODUCT ID}/form_key/{FORM KEY}/`

```
$url = strtr(base64_encode($url), '+/=', '-_,'); // for base64 encode

$form_key = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); // for getting form_key
```

if you use http://{YOUR SITE NAME}/checkout/onepage as redirect url
magento redirect you directly to checkout after product added to cart.

You only have to make a button which redirects to this url. // onclick=setLocation(url);

Answer (score 0):

Kindly open app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Add below line into `<form>` Tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="buy_now" id="buy_now" value="" />
```

Put below button at anywhere where you want

```
<button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_now').val('buy_now');productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="btn btn-block btn-express-buynow"><i class="cart-icon-white m-r-sm v-middle"></i>Buy Now</button>
```

Now open app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

Change the code as below instructions

FInd the line $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl); and replace this line as below code

```
if (!empty($buy_now)) {
    $this->_redirect('onepagecheckout'); // If you are using onepagecheckout or use this $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/')
}else{
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
}
```

Code Taken from this link http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/01/how-to-add-buynow-button-on-product.html

Comment: Are you sure controllers can be re-written this way ?

Comment: You  can override the cart controller from your own module with the help of config.xml

Comment: Then please mention that too in your answer. It is a little misleading right now.