# Magento Buy Now Button for Configurable Products

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, addtocart

I Need Add a Buy Now Button For Direct Checkout.

I Have Coded But Not Working For Configurable Products.

If There Are Any Extension For That Please Suggest Me.

Comment: Can u please share code?

Comment: Why you roll back commit

Comment: i dont think it should be edit.

Comment: we are editing the question for improve the standard of question for all  community member, by  add tags & content edit. For your case,i  thought , we need to improve content formating

Answer (score 3):

There are two way to Can do it

### 1.Use existing Add to Cart

First, change **Add to Cart** Button to **Buy Now**.

Then add a hidden input field to the ***#product_addtocart_form*** form. Name should be ***return_url*** and its value should be `<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>"`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>" name="return_url" />
```

### 2.add a button Buy now with exits add to cart button

If you want ***both Add to Cart and Buy now***, add the **buy now** button to `addtoCart.phtml`

```
<button type="button" 
        title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>"
        class="button btn-cart" 
        onclick="productBuyNowForm.submit(this)">
    <span><span>Buynow</span></span>
</button>
```

On that buttons onlick event, a custom `VarienForm` is used, `productBuyNowForm.submit(this)`, which will submit this form and redirect to checkout onepage.

**To define this custom form, add the following JavaScript code at view.phtml**

```
var productBuyNowForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productBuyNowForm.submit = function (button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;
        alert(form.action);
        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }

        /* add return Url */
        var inputreturn= document.createElement("input");
        inputreturn.type = "hidden";
        inputreturn.name = "return_url";
        inputreturn.value = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>";
        document.getElementById('product_addtocart_form').appendChild(inputreturn);
        /* add return Url */
        // Append a line break 
        var e = null;
        try {
            this.form.submit();
        } catch (e) {
        }
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }

        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}.bind(productBuyNowForm);
```

Also ,need to add below code after `productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {` at view.phtml

```
if(!document.getElementsByName("return_url")){
    var element = document.getElementById("product_addtocart_form");
    var child=document.getElementById("return_url");
    element.removeChild(child);`
}
```

this code is remove field return_url input field whenever ,you have cart from  addtoCart button

Comment: Thank Amit Working fine. but issue with me is i am using Ajax Add to Cart Extension that's why not redirecting at checkout url after click buy now button.

Comment: Just Cart is Updating but url not going at checkout

Comment: you have using  ajax cart.. this is not default  magento feature, so please  ask  new question with   ajax extension resource

Comment: i need Ajax for "Add to Cart" button and after click "Buy Now" button go at checkout

Comment: Got Success !!!  Working now

Comment: Thanks man, this is perfect, I just want to ask you if you can explain a little bit more the last part, that part with removing return_url input field. Because I didn't understand exactly why did you do that and my code works without that part. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you please mention the location of view.phtml? @AmitBera

Comment: view.phtml is not found in 2.3.3?

Comment: Please check the question. Question is related with Magento 1.9 Not Magento 2.X version